# Group by NULL values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to select all unique rows from multiple tables, and where they are the same across tables add the totals togther.

This is working ok, except for in cases where there are NULL values in a column across the two tables. In each individual table they are being grouped together, but aren't being joined on the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE t1(col1   VARCHAR2 (1),col2   VARCHAR2 (1));

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('A', 'A');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('A', 'B');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (NULL, 'A');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (NULL, 'B');
CREATE TABLE t2 AS SELECT * FROM t1;
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (NULL, 'B');
```

Select query:

```
SELECT NVL (count_1, 0) + NVL (count_2, 0) AS TOTAL, col1, col2
  FROM (  SELECT col1, col2, COUNT (1) count_1
            FROM t1
        GROUP BY col1, col2) t1
       FULL OUTER JOIN (  SELECT col1, col2, COUNT (1) count_2
                            FROM t2
                        GROUP BY col1, col2) t2
          USING (col1, col2)
```

Result:

```
TOTAL   COL1    COL2
2       A       A
2       A       B
1               A
1               B
2               B
1               A
```

Disired result

```
TOTAL   COL1    COL2
2       A       A
2       A       B
2               A
3               B
```

I have tried using

```
nvl(col1,'N'), nvl(col2,'N')
```

However this produces a syntax error so I'm not using it correctly somehow.

```
CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
```

makes it worse:

```
1   A   A
1   A   B
1       A
2       B
1   A   Y
1   A   Y
1       N
1       N
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select count(*),col1,col2 from
(
 select col1,col2 from t1
 union all
 select col1,col2 from t2
)
group by col1,col2;
```

Comment: This looks like what I want in terms of the result (I need to test it on performance as there may be a reason why it had to be done this way). I guess the simplest options is always the best!

Comment: Just for your own testing, to get your original query working, you'd need to amend the full outer join's join condition from `using (col1, col2)` to something like `ON (NVL(t1.col1, '{NULL}') = NVL(t2.col1, '{NULL}') AND NVL(t1.col2, '{NULL}') = NVL(t2.col2, '{NULL}'))`